# chrome dev tools "save" not working while debugging node.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome

While debugging node.js cli script in chrome dev tools (that is possible http://youtu.be/03qGA-GJXjI), I cannot save the changes I made on the fly like I can when I debug normal javascript from a website. I get an error message:

"Debugger.setScriptSource failed.
LiveEdit Failure: Failed to compile new version of script: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ["

And then a warning:

Saving of live-edit changes back to source files is disabled by configuration.
Change the option "saveLiveEdit" in config.json to enable this feature.

Does anyone know how to fix this? It would be really convenient to debug and edit file and save it while not leaving chrome dev tools.

Thanks.

btw, this is how the config.json looks like, https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector/blob/master/config.json. I tried changing "saveLiveEdit" option to true, but still I get the same message "Saving of live-edit changes back to source files is disabled by configuration.
Change the option "saveLiveEdit" in config.json to enable this feature."

Comment: I finally figured it out, save live editing can work but you have to call node-inspector with a command line option --save-live-edit, and then it will work!

Comment: One more tip, use --no-preload option for faster startup.

Comment: this should be a community wiki.

Comment: In case it's not clear to others reading this, there are ways other than the command line for setting --save-live-edit (and other) node-inspector options, including in a config file. See the [node-inspector npm docs](https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-inspector). I typically set all my inspector config options in a file to save typing time on the command line.

Comment: To understand this issue, you have to realize that node-inspector is using the DevTools to provide UI, but isn't DevTools as you're accustomed to it so you could have Chrome DevTools setup to do live editing and that will have no effect in node-inspector which is really a web-server on it's own. Using the command-line switch or config.json is required to tell node-inspector to enable this behavior and it then uses node fs to modify your project files locally based on changes in the UI in the browser.

Answer (score 5):

This seemed to work for me. I started 2 shells:

1. node-inspector --save-live-edit
2. node --debug app.js

Then go to http://127.0.0.1:8080/?ws=127.0.0.1:8080&port=5858 on your browser.

Making changes to your code should save it on the hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the environment variable `node-inspector_save-live-edit` and set it to `true`. The environment variable `node-inspector_` prefix is scanned by node-inspector.

You can also use $HOME/.node-inspectorrc and store the following:

`{
  "save-live-edit": true,
  "preload": false,
  "hidden": ["node_modules/" ],
  "nodejs": ["--harmony"]
}`

Answer (score 0):

Do not modify **config.json**, changes $YOUR_NPM_PATH\node_modules\node-\lib\config.js instead. Find and modify within the file:

```
'save-live-edit': {
    ...
    ...
    default: true
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the option `--save-live-edit` when launching node-debug.

For example:

`node-debug --save-live-edit app.js`